# Is there a way to guarante DOP for PL/SQL job?

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql, parallel-processing, sqlplus

Very often my parallel PL/SQL jobs end up with error ORA-12842 or a serial execution of the statement. Each job has fixed degree of parallelism (DOP) quota.

Is there a way to hack it and guarante parallelism for each run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think you can literally hack it, but you can definitely avoid ORA-12842 and serial execution.

You can suppress ORA-12842 and silently restart you PL/SQL job.

Give it configurable number of tries and go serial upon final try failure.

Procedure `exec_insert` (from example below) will do  number of tries to execute your DML.
It will start with max DOP of 16 and upon failure silently restart your job with DOP 8, then 4, then 2 and if 2 fails it will go serial.

Set your environment for parallel execution of your DML:

```
procedure parallel_on(p_dop INT:=10) as
begin
  --rollback;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION ENABLE PARALLEL DML';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION FORCE PARALLEL QUERY PARALLEL '||p_dop;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET PARALLEL_MIN_PERCENT=100';
end;--
```

Set your environment for serial execution of your DML:

```
procedure parallel_off as
begin
  --rollback;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION DISABLE PARALLEL DML';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION FORCE PARALLEL QUERY PARALLEL 1';

end;
```

Example of generic DML executor.

```
procedure exec_insert(p_sql varchar2, p_dop IN OUT INT)
as
  v_pn varchar2(32):='EXEC_INSERT';
  insufficient_parallel_q_slaves EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( insufficient_parallel_q_slaves, -12827 );
  v_max_dop INT:=16;
  c_dop INT:=CASE WHEN p_dop>v_max_dop THEN v_max_dop ELSE p_dop END ; --//constant
  v_dop INT:=c_dop; 
begin
--p_start(v_pn);
--p(v_sql);
FOR dop in REVERSE 1..p_dop  LOOP
    if MOD(dop,2)=1 then CONTINUE; end if;
    --p('Trying DOP: '||dop);
    if dop>1 then parallel_on(dop); else parallel_off(); end if;
    begin
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
      --inserted();
      p_dop:=dop;
      commit;
      exit when true;
    exception
      when insufficient_parallel_q_slaves then
        rollback;
        NULL; --//pass
      when others then
        raise;
    end;
    --commit;

  END LOOP;
--p_end(v_pn);
end;
```